# EsriLoader and Angular: basemap without border and streets

Tags: angular, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I'm using the ArcGis esri maps inside my angular 9 application by implementing the esri loader like described in their tutorial. The data requires that there are no borders displayed (operas from 17xx where correct borders are hard to obtain).

Is there a basemap without borders, streets and names of countries. Just a gray shape to distinguish between ocean and land would be enough. City names would also be okay.

Because I wasn't able to find one, I played around with the ArcGis online tool and found out that using the NationalGeographic and setting the transparency of NationalGeographic Style to 100% would fulfill my needs. How can I set the transparency of this layer in my application to 100%?

Would be glad if somebody could help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Let me see if I understand, you want a basemap that only has the continents, is that it? .. BTW, what do you mean with  _"The data requires that there are no borders displayed (operas from 17xx where correct borders are hard to obtain)."_

Comment: Yes exactly, i need a basemap with just continents, because the current borders would lead to a misinterpretation of the data points in the map.

Comment: But I managed to use this layer as my basemap: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=87cf997870f3468c8268c926843b832a
so this solved my problem more or less